# Master degree in 2 countries?

Tags: masters, international-students, international

I am looking for international master degrees which are offered in 2 different countries. For example first year in Singapore and second year in Brasil. How can I find such universities or programs? Is there a big database for such schools?

Answer (score 0):

Such programs are rare enough that I don’t know any. I would look into universities that have campuses in multiple countries, and if they allow you to transfer campuses during the program or something along those lines. That would allow you to get the same effect without there being a specific program for it.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to look at the Erasmus Mundus joint masters degrees ([current list here](https://eacea.ec.europa.eu/erasmus-plus/library/scholarships-catalogue_en)). I did one of these a few years ago, spending one year in Sweden and one year in Germany, but I think that some of the programmes include at least one year outside of Europe. They also offer a number of full scholarships for some (all?) programmes. In my case, this was a great experience both academically and culturally.

Comment: Thanks I live in Europe and I have been to almost all EU countries and would like to see and study in oversea countries.

Answer (score 0):

You can see if the university has an exchange program with another university. If so, then you could possibly split time between two universities, but it may not be a 50-50 split.